# Alternate way to print and sort output

Tags: linux, bash, awk

I have a list of names and scores (First,Last,Score)

I'm trying to print out ONLY the last name that occurs most often in DESCENDING NUMERICAL order.

Here is an example list.

```
inisha__Ohler__1
Loralee__Hippe__5
Boyd__Leslie__8
Donnette__Cosentino__5
Viva__Bedsole__4
Jann__Banfield__3
Alan__Dionne__2
Sandee__Verdun__2
Raeann__Sweetman__3
Judson__Goers__2
Mandie__Salcedo__8
Yesenia__Bibeau__1
Doug__Petteway__9
Alejandra__Winter__9
Marquitta__Sang__7
Rusty__Rodrigue__2
Rickie__Devin__1
Marie__Elem__3
Faustina__Haltom__4
Dorthea__Ervin__4
Yesenia__Bibeau__5
Doug__Petteway__8
Alejandra__Winter__1
Marquitta__Sang__9
Rusty__Rodrigue__4
Yesenia__Bibeau__2
Doug__Petteway__4
Alejandra__Winter__3
Marquitta__Sang__6
Rusty__Rodrigue__6
Rickie__Devin__7
Marie__Elem__1
Faustina__Haltom__2
Dorthea__Ervin__4
```

I want to spit the output out using a single "|" or less.

```
cut -d "_" -f 3 scores | sort -r | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Already works but I am looking for something less expensive.

Comment: you can use `-t _ -k1` on your first `sort` and eliminate the `cut` part of your pipeline. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I believe least expensive way to achieve the same is by using `awk` with sort as follows:

```
awk -F"__" '{ count[$2]++ } END {for (word in count) print count[word], word}' < scores | sort -r
```

and in case if you also want those three spaces in the beginning just like `uniq -c` provides you,

```
awk -F"__" '{ count[$2]++ } END {for (word in count) print "  ", count[word], word}' < scores | sort -r
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU awk-specific:

```
$ gawk -F__ '{ names[$2]++ }
             END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc";
                   for (n in names) { print n }
             }' input.txt
Sang
etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this perl one-liner

```
perl -aF/__/ -ne '$h{$F[1]}++; END{ print"$$_[0]\t$$_[1]\n" for sort {$$b[0]<=>$$a[0]} map {[$h{$_},$_]} keys %h }' <scores
```

or to show only the name that occurs most often

```
perl -MList::Util=max -aF/__/ -ne '$h{$F[1]}++; END{ $max=max(values%h); print "$h{$_}\t$_\n" for grep {$h{$_}==$max} keys%h }' <scores
```